# Как получить доступ к iframe с видеороликом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Как при вызове всплывающего окна с видеороликом из `YouTube` (новый `fancybox 3.5.7`) в `beforeShow` получить `id` элемента `iframe`, в котором будет размещено видео? Смотрю по примеру в интернете, но пример, видимо, для старой версии - `fancybox 2.1.7` - там делается так:

```
var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');
```

Но данный объект в новой версии `fancybox` не определен.

Answer (score 0):

Как получить объект в `beforeShow` - так и не разобрался, а в `afterShow` можно получить так:

```
var id = jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().current.$content.find('iframe').attr('id');
```